# Does AssertJ provide an assertion method on iterables that has a Consumer as argument?

Tags: java, assertj

AssertJ provides the method `hasValueSatisfying(Consumer<T> requirement)` for Java `Optional` objects. This method allows to create assertions on the optional value like this:

```
    assertThat(myOptional).hasValueSatisfying(v -> {
        assertThat(v.getFirstName()).isEqualTo("Stephen");
        assertThat(v.getLastName()).isEqualTo("Smith");
        assertThat(v.getAge()).isEqualTo(22);
    });
```

Is there any equivalent method for collections?
Of cause I can misuse the method `allMatch(Predicate<? super T> predicate)` like this

```
    assertThat(myIcelanderFriends).extracting(Person::getAddress)
                    .allMatch(a -> {
                        assertThat(a.getCountry()).isEqualTo("Iceland");
                        assertThat(a.getPhoneContryCode()).isEqualTo("+354");
                        assertThat(a.getSurname()).endsWith("son");
                        return true; // Predictes must return a boolean
                    });
```

but then I have to add the misleading `return true;` line as a Predicate needs a return value. I'd prefer to have here also `haveValuesSatisfying(Consumer<T> requirement)` method.
Did I oversee such a method or does it not exist (yet)?

Comment: `myIcelanderFriends.stream().map(Person::getAddress).forEach(a -> { assertThat(...); ...});` ?

Comment: @JBNizet Of cause your suggestion is a valid solution. However, from my point of view it has the disadvantage that I cannot imidiately see that this line of code performs some assertions, as it does not start with `assertThat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope there is no such method yet ... but will be in 3.6.0 :
https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/711

Comment: @Joern this has been fixed, will be in AssertJ 3.6.0 published in few weeks.